# process image brightness using uislider in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have implemented changing the brightness of an image using uislider in iPhone without using openGlImageProcessing. I want to change the brightness of particular area of an image only not the whole image, only particular area of an image should be get brightnessed for example the central area of an image should get brightnessed or particular color from an entire image should get brightnessed. How can we change the brightness of particular portion of an image. Please help me to solve the problem, code is

```
CGImageRef imageRef = imageView.image.CGImage;
CFDataRef ref = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)); 
UInt8 * buf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(ref); 
int length = CFDataGetLength(ref);

NSLog(@"%i",val);
float value = val/100;
for(int i=0; i<length; i+=3)
{
    Byte tempR = buf[i + 1];
    Byte tempG = buf[i + 2];
    Byte tempB = buf[i + 3];

    int outputRed = value + tempR;
    int outputGreen = value + tempG;
    int outputBlue = value + tempB;

    if (outputRed>255) outputRed=255;
    if (outputGreen>255) outputGreen=255;
    if (outputBlue>255) outputBlue=255;

    if (outputRed<0) outputRed=0;
    if (outputGreen<0) outputGreen=0;
    if (outputBlue<0) outputBlue=0;


    buf[i + 1] = outputRed; 
    buf[i + 2] = outputGreen; 
    buf[i + 3] = outputBlue;


}

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);


CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(buf, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef));

CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
if (value == 0) {
    imageView.image = image;
}
else
{
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:img]];
}

CFRelease(ref);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(img);
```

Comment: how do u come to know which part of the image's brightness to be changed.. getting it from touches?

Comment: no just say central area to be get brighnessed or only particular color should be get brightnessed

Comment: Can't you just adjust the offset into your image buffer and run the loop on a smaller section?

Comment: please tell me in detail, i am not getting what u mean

Comment: are u able to change brightness of whole image.. if yes then you can crop the required area & edit it. and on a view u can add these 2 images one on other, and take a screenshot, which gives a single image  edited one.

Comment: @Rocky I'm guessing that you have copied that code from somewhere else rather than writing it yourself. I would suggest that you go through it and work out what it is doing so you can understand how to change it rather than just copying chunks of code from places. It will help you grow your development skills.

Comment: i am trying but i am not getting it please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching i got the answer as

```
//origional image
 image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images2.jpg"];
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

 CGSize size = [image size];

 [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
 [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView release];   

 //image to be brightnessed
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake([image size].width / 6, [image size].height / 6 , 
                         ([image size].width / 2), ([image size].height / 2));

 CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
 [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake([image size].width / 6, [image size].height / 6, ([image  size].width / 2), ([image size].height / 2))];
 [self.view addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView release];
```